# Move Vote to Close button back (aka who moved my cheese)

Tags: support, design, vote-to-close

Can we get the Vote to Close button back to the right? My muscle memory keeps me wanting to move to the right like how *most* dialogs work and how it used to be.

[image]

Comment: OK, good. I wasn't sure if I was going insane or not but every time I was instinctively going to the right to click the button. I was just ready to try and found screenshots of the old screen to see if it was just me or was it actually moved.